# Fetching table already exist from database

Tags: php, laravel

I have several tables already exists in database name`education`, How can I fetch all tables to laravel.
for example I have a table name `students` - 
I didn't make it by laravel it already existed - when I type in terminal

`php artisan make:model students`

It creates a file name in App folder as `students.php` but when try

`return students::all()`

in controller folder  I get this error

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'education.students' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
>   `students`)"

Comment: Can you share your controller method that is throwing this error?

Comment: Add the controller and the model codes, please. By now, it seems that the `students` doesn't exists at all (maybe has another name?) or the model is not correctly attached to the table (see AdityaThakur's answer in such case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating a model but you are not creating a table in your database.
if you have a table created already then you can simply add

```
protected $table = 'students';
```

to your model
// or the table name that corresponds to this table

else what you need to do is create a migration using

`php artisan make:migration create_students_table`

then you can add field to this table in your migration file in your 'database\migrations' folder. Once you are done with fields you need to migrate the migration using

`php artisan migrate`

Comment: WOW, Thanks **Aditya**